# How can I save a Pokemon I want to keep so I can restart the game (without using the Pokebank)?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I found out that male customization sucks in X/Y, so I'd like to start over as a female character.

However, I got *Absol* from Wondertrade and I'd like to keep it on the new save. I know that you can use Pokemon bank, but my family doesn't allow me to "buy" it.
So my question is how can I do so *without* Pokemon Bank?

Comment: Do you have a friend you can trade with?

Comment: I don't think so... @Timelord64

Comment: I believe this is a different question to the one it was [duplicated to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/155016/28182), as that question is whether a new save can withdraw Pokemon from the Bank, not whether it's possible to save a Pokemon without using the bank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Timelord64 asked a good question. Without PokéBank, you can only resort to trading. If you can find someone who is willing to give you your Pokémon back when you need it, you will be able to "save" your Pokémon thus getting it back after you restart your current progress.

Otherwise, note that Absol can be found and caught on Route 8 on both X and Y games and in Friend Safari if you have a friend with that Pokémon in friend safari.

Comment: @Timelord64: You can trade with me (via internet wifi) if you want to. We'll have to decide on the date and time we can get online and do the trades.

Comment: I decided to restart without my pokemons because I didn't have anything rare or amazingly good. Except that Absol. It would've been good one to start with, but who knows if I get Absol again ^^

Comment: @SilverWolfGaming Okay, good luck then :)